# Reload modified system plist

Tags: plist

I tried modifying a preference pane plist (with defaults write), but the change doesn’t take effect. Is there a way to make that happen?

Comment: You may need to kill the defaults server.

Comment: @fd0: How is that done?

Answer (score 5):

Assuming a newer version of OS X (10.9+ ?).

You have to kill two processes: the process that manages the preference you are modifying (e.g. killall Finder if it is com.apple.finder that you are modifying) and "cfprefsd".

"cfprefsd" is a newer preference caching service of OS X.

In Terminal.app: `killall cfprefsd && killall Finder`.

You could also restart your computer.