# How can I get back menu bar icon of an agent app?

Tags: macos, menu-bar, plist

I use Clipy.app and it's an "[agent app](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/lsuielement?language=objc)", which means it runs in the background and doesn't appear in the Dock.

By default, it shows the app icon on the top right of the menu bar of Mac. However, I remove the icon by mouse dragging with holding `command`. Then I can't find the icon anymore, even if I re-install the app.

How can I get back menu bar icon of Clipy.app?

Comment: Presumably the app file will still be on your disk -- in Applications? Try launching it from there.

Comment: @benwiggy yes, in `/Applications`. I force quit the app and try to re-launch from there, but nothing happens.

Comment: I'd suggest asking the developers.

Comment: Have you tried its preferences file? `defaults delete com.clipy-app.Clipy kCPYPrefShowStatusItemKey`

Comment: @Redarm wow! `defaults delete com.clipy-app.Clipy kCPYPrefShowStatusItemKey` works and the icon comes back. But what's mean of `kCPYPrefShowStatusItemKey`? and how do you know the specific name `com.clipy-app.Clipy`?

Comment: "kCPYPrefShowStatusItemKey" is the preference key for the menu bar item, since you can choose one, or "none".  I've long been using "ClipMenu" (as mentioned at the bottom of this page: https://clipy-app.com ), so I went ahead and installed Clipy to check it out.  That's how I now know the name of its preference file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the whole and especially if the application is not self-contained in the app sandbox one should also delete its preference file, which usually can be found in `~/Library/Preferences/`.  Searching for the application's name in that folder in many cases yields a result.

Had it been self contained, the application would have had a container in...

```
~/Library/Containers/
```

or

```
~/Library/Group Containers/
```

...which would include its Preference file within.  In this case the whole container could be removed.

Delete the .plist file and either reboot, or see also here:
[Reload modified system plist](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/205596/reload-modified-system-plist/205616#205616)

Another way to find the plist's name:

```
a=$(defaults domains | sed 's/,/\\n/g'); printf "$a" | grep "Clipy"
```

In your specific case, deleting the menu bar item key from the preference file did the trick:

```
defaults delete com.clipy-app.Clipy kCPYPrefShowStatusItemKey
```

"kCPYPrefShowStatusItemKey" by default is not present, unless one changes the menu bar icon, or it has been set to 'none'.

PS.Setting the menu bar item to 'none' implies that one wants to solely use the shortcut keys to launch windows like the "history" window, which includes a link to "Preferences" and therefore a way to change the menu bar item.  So it would be good to remember them and to make sure the shortcut keys are functional.